# Laravel: Class 'HTML' not found when autoloading my own files with composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am using Laravel 4.1 and i have a file called html.php, in that file i use HTML::. Right now I am loading that file with this code in bootstrap/start.php right before return $app;

```
require $app['path.base'].'/app/macros/html.php';
```

I don't know if that is "okay" or not, so now I am trying to autoload html.php in composer.json instead, with this:

```
"files": [
    "app/macros/html.php"
]
```

But when I do that, i get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'HTML' not found in /app/macros/html.php on line 9
```

Line 9 look like this:

```
HTML::macro("flash", function(){
```

What am I doing wrong?

And am I wrong when thinking that loading html.php in composer.json is prettier than doing it in bootstrap/start.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot load your macro file from composer, since that'll load it up before Laravel's stuff and you won't have access to the HTML facade yet.

The correct place to put this is at the bottom of **app/start/global.php**:

```
require app_path().'/filters.php';
require app_path().'/macros/html.php';
```

Comment: Thank you Joseph! That works and I will use that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgot to do the following:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: I already did that and I think my html.php file is loading like it should, because thats where the error is.